# Can Apache Drill parse a SQL statement for table names?

Tags: sql, parsing, apache-drill

I have an existing Java project in Eclipse and I want to be able to parse a SQL statement that a user will input in order to find the table names in the statement. Is it possible for Apache Drill to accomplish this task, and if so how do I go about doing it?

I have been looking at the documentation for Drill but all I can find is a way to create functions in Eclipse that can later be used in Command Prompt. However, what I want is a way to use some sort of parsing function inside the Java project to find the table names in the user input.

Answer (score 0):

You can [JSQL Parser](https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser) for getting *table names* from SQL statement. Find documentation [here](https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser/wiki/Examples-of-SQL-parsing#extract-table-names-from-sql).

Answer (score -1):

This is not task for Apache Drill, but you can use rich SQL parser in isolation from Apache Calcite toolkit http://calcite.apache.org/.